# How can I modify kwarg_values?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm working with this code from [mplsoccer](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/pizza_plots/plot_pizza_colorful.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pizza-plots-plot-pizza-colorful-py):

```
### Plotting
from urllib.request import urlopen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from mplsoccer import PyPizza, add_image, FontManager

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 400

font_normal = "Bahnschrift"

# color for the slices and text
slice_colors = [color1] * 6 + [color2] * 6 + [color3] * 2
text_colors = ["#ffffff"] * 14

# instantiate PyPizza class
baker = PyPizza(
    params=params,                  # list of parameters
    background_color="#e9ecef",     # background color
    straight_line_color="#e9ecef",  # color for straight lines
    straight_line_lw=1,             # linewidth for straight lines
    last_circle_lw=0,               # linewidth of last circle
    other_circle_lw=0,              # linewidth for other circles
    inner_circle_size=10            # size of inner circle
)

# plot pizza
fig, ax = baker.make_pizza(
    values,                          # list of values
    figsize=(8, 8.5),                # adjust figsize according to your need
    color_blank_space="same",        # use same color to fill blank space
    slice_colors=slice_colors,       # color for individual slices
    value_colors=text_colors,        # color for the value-text
    value_bck_colors=slice_colors,   # color for the blank spaces
    blank_alpha=0.4,                 # alpha for blank-space colors
    kwargs_slices=dict(
        edgecolor="#e9ecef", zorder=2, linewidth=1, alpha=.9,
    ),                               # values to be used when plotting slices
    kwargs_params=dict(
        color="#000000", fontsize=10,
        fontproperties=font_normal, va="center"
    ),
    kwargs_values=dict(
        color="#000000", fontsize=10,
        fontproperties=font_normal, zorder=3,
        va="center",
        alpha=1,
        bbox=dict(
            edgecolor="#ffffff", facecolor="cornflowerblue",
            boxstyle="round,pad=0.3", lw=1
        )
    )
                               # values to be used when adding parameter-values
)
```

I want to edit it so that `kwargs_values` shows raw values instead of percentile which can already be guessed by the lenght of the slices. I created a list named `rawdata` with the same length as the values list, but I don't know how to specify that I want `rawdata` to be displayed instead of values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly through `kwargs_values` currently. However, it is possible to do this by editing the labels after drawing them:

```
texts = baker.get_value_texts()
for i, text in enumerate(texts):
    text.set_text(str(values[i]))
```